# Why does my str_getcsv no longer work - or is it something else?

Tags: php

I have a problem and have been looking for an answer for 4 days - mainly on Google, but have hit a brick wall.

Can anybody help?  Please.

**HERE IS THE BACKGROUND :**

All my web-pages are .php files.

I invite visitors to give me an alias name and an email address - using  a form on a web-page.

I store the alias and email in a .txt file on my server.

I don't want the email to be in plain text but I am not looking for a clever encryption routine - I hold no other information about the visitor.

My quick and easy solution is to swap each bit in each character by using the PHP Binary NOT Operator ( ~ ).

Thus :   $code = ~$email  results in "abc" being coded (in Hex) from 61 62 63 to 9E 9D 9C

**HERE IS HOW I WRITE TO AND READ FROM THE .txt FILE :**

I use a form to get the "alias" and "email" from the visitor which I "post" to "savethisperson.php".
In "savethisperson.php" I use the following code -

CODE SNIPPET 1

```
  $fd = fopen("persondata.txt", "a");    
  fwrite($fd, $_POST['alias'] . ",");    
  fwrite($fd, ~$_POST['email']);        // note the encryption of the string using ~    
  fwrite($fd, "\r\n");    
  fclose($fd);
```

You will note that this creates one line per visitor with two strings in the line separated by a comma.

I now want to list every line in the "persondata.txt" file, showing the encrypted code -

CODE SNIPPET 2

```
  $members = file("persondata.txt");   // Creates an array called "members" with one line in each element of the array.    
  foreach ($members as $nxtline)       // Creates variable called "nxtline" for each element in turn    
  {     
    echo $nxtline, "<br>";    
  }
```

I now want to list every line in the "persondata.txt" file, un-encrypting the email address -

CODE SNIPPET 3

```
  $members = file("persondata.txt");   // Creates an array called "members" with one line in each element of the array.    
  foreach ($members as $nxtline)       // Creates variable called "nxtline" for each element in turn    
  { $data = str_getcsv($nxtline);      // Creates an array called "data" for each string separated by a comma.    
    echo $data[0]), "," ~$data[1], "<br>";  // Note the un-encryption of data[1] using ~    
  }
```

**SO HERE IS MY PROBLEM?**

I have changed my server provider and some of the above code has stopped working.

My old provider offered PHP version 5.4.   Everything worked.

My local (on my own machine) testing server uses PHP 5.3.8.  Everything works.

My new provider offers PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.27 and I am having problems :

Code snippet 1 works.

Code snippet 2 works.

Code snippet 3 fails.  So I assume that it is the "str_getcsv" function that fails with code in the (Hex) 8* and 9* range.  But why would it work before and still work on my testing server?

Perhaps my assumption is wrong and there is some other reason for snippet 3 to stop working.

If it matters - all  servers use Apache 2.0 handler.

PLEASE do not tell me to alter my encryption method.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($data)` and `var_dump($members)` to make sure you're reading the file correctly and str_getcsv is pulling things in correctly? And if you won't alter your "encryption", then at least stop CALLING it encryption. At best it's obfuscation.

Comment: *"My new provider offers PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.27 and I am having problems"* - [**str_getcsv**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) - `(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)` - **See Also** [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) - Gets line from file pointer and parse for CSV fields. - So, PHP version.

Comment: @Marc B - OK, no problem, I'll call it obfuscation.  I only need the email address in order to make contact - there is no other information available on the website.  I just wanted to make it less likely that crawlers would easily find a new source of email addresses to spam.

Comment: then don't put that file in your site's document root. PHP couldn't care less where on the server the file is - it's not bound by webserver document root restrictions at all.

Comment: @Mark B - I don't know var_dump(... ...) - I will  do some research.

Comment: @ Fred -ii- I know that str_getcsv was introduced in PHP 5.  All the servers referred to are there or later - hence my problem

Comment: @Marc B  -  Thanks. I have used both var_dump($data) and var_dump($nxtline).  The characters above (Hex) 8* are clearly there in $nxtline but not in $data[1]. They disappear after the str_getcsv routine.  I think that I should post a new (more restricted) question.
Isn't there a way to "tick" your answer as a thankyou.  How do I do  that ?